# Send message via lync using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, lync-2010, lync

Is there a way to send message to lync via powershell. My scenario is like this.
My teammate may request for some task and i will initiate the powershell script to complete that task. It will send mail at the end. Instead of mail if it sends message via Lync it will be much more intuitive. Is there a way to do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you'll need to install the Lync SDK first. You can then use powershell to create SDK objects and use them as you would in a .NET application.

This article walks through the process nicely - http://blogs.technet.com/b/csps/archive/2011/05/05/sendim.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope it will be much more useful for our team

Comment: Mentioned link is dead.